# run pm2 logs error SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, serversocket

I want to see logs of my project

Steps :

1. I clone a socket app. Then I run `npm install pm2 -g` to install pm2
2. I run `pm2 start`

It works. It display a table of my socket app

But if I run `pm2 logs` to see logs, there exist error like this :

```
1|mycompany | C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
1|mycompany | (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
1|mycompany |                                                               ^
1|mycompany |
1|mycompany | SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
1|mycompany |     at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
1|mycompany |     at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
1|mycompany |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
1|mycompany |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
1|mycompany |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
1|mycompany |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
1|mycompany |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
1|mycompany |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
1|mycompany |     at C:\Users\Chelsea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainer.js:295:23
1|mycompany |     at C:\Users\Chelsea\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\async\internal\once.js:12:16
```

I try to run `npm install socket.io express --save` and `npm install jquery --save`, it's the same. there exist error above

How can I solve this problem?
`

**Update** :

`C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD` like this :

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)

SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)
IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the error message:

```
1|mycompany | (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
```

Try to remove `:` after `{` in `C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1` file.

**Update:**
I noticed that pm2 is tring to execute the `NPM.CMD` file as a js module. That's not possible for running a windows CMD file as a js module.
If you installed Git on your windows, you can try running the pm2 from the `git-bash` which was a Linux-like terminal.

**Update**
[You can try this answer from others](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3657#issuecomment-482010714)

Comment: Where I remove it?

Comment: @SuccessMan It seems that file was edited by accident. Can you post that file content here?

Comment: I never edited it. it's automatic. See my question. I had update it

Comment: @SuccessMan Updated the answer.

Comment: @SuccessMan After I search the Internet.you are not alonesee the update answer

Comment: Thank you for the GitHub link to the suggested solution (using a direct path to the `.js` file). I was bashing my head for 2 days!