# pm2 command error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token' in linux environment

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, pm2

Found similar questions but none helped in my case:

[run pm2 logs error SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975906/run-pm2-logs-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

[pm2 Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834021/pm2-unexpected-token-import)

The versions for my node, npm and pm2 are:

node: `v6.14.3`

npm: `v3.10.10`

pm2: `v2.10.2`

I'm trying to deploy an angular app with `pm2` in my corporate linux environment that has no internet access. I have installed `pm2` via the command below from my corporate artifact repository by setting npm registry:

```
$ npm install -g pm2
```

Installation was successful and I could see a folder in my node modules folder at `/home/MY_ID/node_modules/pm2`. Somehow the path variable was not set so I was not able to run any `pm2` command. So I ran the following command in my terminal to set `pm2` path variable:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/MY_ID/node_modules/pm2/bin
```

After which I tried running command `pm2 -v` to check for `pm2`, I got the error below:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/MY_ID/node_modules/pm2/constants.js:10:14)
```

May I know what did I do wrong here? Could it be that the path was set wrongly or the `pm2` was not installed properly?

Comment: Which NodeJS version is on that corporate linux environment?

Comment: node version 6.14.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From pm2's [github page](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2):

> All Node.js versions are supported starting Node.js 8.X.

You need to install a more recent version of nodejs (at least v 10, v6 is very old).

Regarding that error, the problem might be that pm2 is using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) with an object, which is not supported until nodejs 8.3 (or v 8.0 running with `--harmony` flag).

Example

```
let clone = {...object};
```